# What does the architecture mean from java class file?

Tags: java, tomcat

I just built Tomcat7, and used `file` command to check the generated class files, it prints as below

```
output/classes/org/apache/coyote/AbstractProcessor$1.class:   compiled Java class data, version 52.0 [64-bit architecture=65593] [architecture=6382440]
output/classes/org/apache/coyote/AbstractProcessor.class:     compiled Java class data, version 52.0 [architecture=14878464] [architecture=56073]
```

What does the architecture means in the output? Why compiler generates differently for the classes from a same file?

And why did the compiler generate `AbstractProcessor$1.class` for https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/7.0.x/java/org/apache/coyote/AbstractProcessor.java? There is no anonymous inner class in source code.

Comment: Classes with `$` are usually anonymous classes used inside other classes, insde `AbstractProcessor` in your case.

Comment: But which does not explain why compiler generates differently from them.

Comment: An anonymous class is still a class, it has to be compiled to its own class file.

Comment: @Arnaud OP is not asking what `$1` is, but what `[64-bit architecture=65593] [architecture=6382440]` and `[architecture=14878464] [architecture=56073]` that are in the continuation of the line are (scroll right to see them), and why they differ when (presumably) the class files were produced by the same compiler at the same time.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks @Amadan.

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe it only shows up on Mac version of `file`, not Linux one, and Mac's is (AFAIK) closed-source. I have no clue what those numbers represent.

Comment: Actually I see this on a linux host, kernel `4.9.184-0.1.ac.235.83.329.metal1.x86_64`.

Comment: @brookhong: the kernel version is not relevant here, what does `file -version` show, because the `file` version is probably relevant here.

Comment: $file --version
file-5.22
magic file from /etc/magic:/usr/share/misc/magic

Comment: @brookhong: then that issue might already be fixed. I'm using 5.37 and the latest release is 5.38.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks. The reason I cared about it is that `jdb` always reports wrong line number for class `AbstractProcessor`, but correct line number for another  class `Response` under the same path.

Comment: @brookhong: that seems like a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why don't you post that as a new question (potentially referring to this one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is actually a bug in the `file` command. Looking at [the file `cafebabe`](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/cafebabe) in the `file` github mirror, which handles detecting both Java class files and Mach-O (i.e. Mac) binaries (because they both use the same magic strings), it seems that the "architecture" part is meant to only be used for the latter, but somehow gets applied to your class files.

Feel free to ignore that.

Regarding the $1 file, looking at it with javap shows that it is a synthetic class and contains a method named `$SwitchMap$org$apache$tomcat$util$log$UserDataHelper$Mode` (sic), suggesting that it is generated by the compiler to help with the switch statement in the code:

```
$ javap AbstractProcessor\$1.class 
Compiled from "AbstractProcessor.java"
class org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor$1 {
  static final int[] $SwitchMap$org$apache$tomcat$util$log$UserDataHelper$Mode;
  static {};
}
```

Comment: I'm no `file` expert, but there's a chance that the commit that fixed this is `https://github.com/file/file/commit/724e39ee1a2d7020bc0c39210d0050e0f69ac3c6#diff-51eee6a2312f3e0ba5f695708b2f9eff` which was first included in file-5.23.